# "You're a crooked jerky jockey, and you drive a crooked hoss!" -- What's a Hoss?

Tags: slang, archaicisms, songs

So, it's that time of year, and every once in a while I'll hear the Grinch's tune on the radio. One line that has always confused me is the line

> You're a crooked jerky jockey, and you drive a crooked hoss!

Given the phrase "Jockey", I'm inclined to believe that "Hoss" is a purposeful mispronunciation of "Horse" in order to keep the flow of the song, but I've never heard of a horse being "Driven" only "Ridden". Is Hoss an archaic slang term for something else? A type of automobile maybe?

Comment: You can certainly [drive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drive) a horse, though as you would drive cattle, deer, or mules, and not as you would drive a car, a golf ball, or a public debate.

Comment: @choster You can drive a horse to water, and he's more likely to drink if you put salt in his hay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[hoss](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/hoss) [OXD]

> nonstandard spelling of horse, used to represent dialect or informal speech

[drive](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/drive) [OXD]

> 4.2 Force (someone) to work to an excessive extent.

Comment: "Drive" is also used to refer to "encouraging" a team of horses pulling a wagon, even when the "work" is nowhere near "excessive".

Answer (score 4):

“Hoss” certainly means “horse” here.

The same simplification of /rs/ to /s/ has occurred in a number of other words (often in informal or dialectal forms): *cuss* for *curse,* apparently the verb *bust* for *burst,* and American English *[ass](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ass#etymonline_v_17955)* for *arse* (the form *arse* seems to have pretty much gone extinct in American English).